# wget of binary file piped into other commands on windows breaks the binary

Tags: windows, unix, wget

This is possibly pushing the boundaries between stackoverflow and serverfault, but here goes.  I am trying to wget a war file from a maven repo, then copy it to a remote system in a deploy directory.  This is what I have:

```
wget -qO- http://somerepo/nexus/content/group/public/com/mycomp/myartifact-0.0.1.war | 
    ssh remotesystem "cat > /path/to/appserver/deploy/myartifact.war
```

*Note, this is broken up to 2 lines for readability*

The problem is that when I run this on windows, the `-qO-` that causes the output to redirect to `STDOUT` (the `q` part just quiets the commentary) is also causing windows to translate `0A` to `0D0a`, or LF to CRLF.  I can just dos2unix the output, but wonder if there is a way to do this without the extra step.  Any ideas?

-------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------

Before anyone mentions it, i can do this:

```
wget -qO- http://somerepo/nexus/content/group/public/com/mycomp/myartifact-0.0.1.war | 
    ssh remotesystem "cat | dos2unix > /path/to/appserver/deploy/myartifact.war
```

But ICK!  Why is wget adding CR to a binary file?  I know its going to STDOUT, but the only reason binary would be going to STDOUT would be so it could be piped into something.  Binary is binary, it never makes sense to inject characters into binary...

-------------------------- EDIT 2 ---------------------------------

My version of wget seems to be 1.11.4

```
C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GetGnuWin32\gnuwin32\bin\wget" -V
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GetGnuWin32\gnuwin32/etc/wgetrc
GNU Wget 1.11.4

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Currently maintained by Micah Cowan <micah@cowan.name>.
```

This was obtained using `GetGnuWin32`

Comment: What version of wget?  It seems to have been fixed sometime after 1.11.4, though there seems to be question as to whether or not 1.12 (and later) will even build on Windows.  In 5 minutes of Googling I couldn't find anybody hosting anything beyond 1.12 (not sure if it's fixed in that build).  You could try compiling the source yourself.

Comment: @Luke, I added my version information to the question above (1.11.4), when you say sometime after 1.11.4, you mean _after_ right?  Any suggestions for where I could obtain a later version for winblows?

Comment: I don't know what "winblows" is.  Anyway, [this](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) allegedly includes wget 1.12; not sure if that includes the binary mode fix, though, and I can't find binaries for any later version anywhere.

Comment: @Luke, he he, just a linux guys attempt at humor...  So, MinGW may have it...  Thats interesting.  I'll have take a look, thanks for the assist!

Comment: If you are still looking, try Cygwin. Their wget version is currently at 1.13.4.

Comment: @Luke, would you mind putting your comment about it being a bug in version 1.11.4 and earlier in the form of a question so I can accept it as an answer?